# Python pexpect sendline contents being buffered?

Tags: python, buffering, pexpect

I have the following code in Python using the pexpect module to run a perl script which asks a series of questions. I have used this for quite some time and works well until now.

### pexpect python

```
index = child.expect(['Question 1:'])
os.system('sleep 2')
print 'Question 1:' + 'answer1'
child.sendline('answer1')

index = child.expect(['Question 2:'])
os.system('sleep 2')
print 'Question 1:' + 'answer2'
child.sendline('answer2')

index = child.expect(['Question 3:'])
os.system('sleep 2')
print 'Question 1:' + 'answer2'
child.sendline('answer2')
```

At this point, i have some code that checks if error will output when Question 2 & Question 3 does not match. I checked the pexpect log and the statements being sent are exactly what i want (number of bytes and string).

However when I check what gets accepted by the perl code its getting the following:

Question 1: 'answer 1'     <-- CORRECT

Question 2: 'answer 1'     <-- INCORRECT

Question 3: 'answer 2answer 2'     <-- its being combined into one for some reason

Any ideas out there? I'm not using anything special when spawning my pexpect object: `child=pexpect.spawn(cmd,timeout=140)`

Edit: Added the perl code function that asks for Question 2 & 3

### **sub getpw**

```
sub getpw
{   my ($name, $var, $encoding) = @_;
    my $pw = $$var;

    PWD: while(1) {
        system("/bin/stty -echo");
        getvar($name, \$pw, 1);
        print "\n";
        system("/bin/stty echo");
        return if $pw eq $$var && length($pw) == 80;
        if (length($pw) > 32) {
            print STDERR "ERROR: Password cannot exceed 32 characters, please reenter.\n";
            next PWD;
        }

        return if $pw eq $$var;

        my $pw2;
        system("/bin/stty -echo");
        getvar("Repeat password", \$pw2, 1);
        print "\n";
        system("/bin/stty echo");
        print "#1: ";
        print $pw;
        print "\n";
        print "#2: ";
        print $pw2;
        if ($pw2 ne $pw) {
            print STDERR "ERROR: Passwords do not match, please reenter.\n";
            next PWD;
        }
        last;
    }

    # Escape dangerous shell characters
    $pw =~ s/([ ;\*\|`&\$!#\(\)\[\]\{\}:'"])/\\$1/g;

    my $correctlength=80;
    my $encoded=`$AVTAR --quiet --encodepass=$pw`;

    chomp($encoded);
    if($? == 0 && length($encoded) == $correctlength) {
        $$var = $encoded;
    } else {
        print "Warning: Password could not be encoded.\n";
        $$var = $pw;
    }
}
```

### sub getvar

```
sub getvar
{   my ($name, $var, $hide) = @_;
    my $default = $$var;
    while(1) {
        if($default) {
            $default = "*****" if $hide;
            print "$name [$default]: ";
        } else {
            print "$name: ";
        }
        my $val = <STDIN>;
        chomp $val;
        ### $val =~ s/ //g;  # do not mess with the password
        $$var = $val if $val;
        last if $$var;
        print "ERROR: You must enter a value\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code on the python side. Check your perl side of the code. To demonstrate I have created below a python questions and answers scripts that call each other. When you execute `answers.py` it will produce the expected output as below. Also you don't need to do the sleep statements child.expect will block until the expected output has been received.

**questions.py**

```
answers = {}
for i in range(1, 4):
    answers[i] = raw_input('Question %s:' % i)
print 'resuls:'
print answers
```

**answers.py**

```
import pexpect
child=pexpect.spawn('./questions.py', timeout=140)
for i in range(1, 4):
    index = child.expect('Question %s:' % i)
    child.sendline('answer%s' % i)

child.expect('resuls:')
print child.read()
```

**output**

```
{1: 'answer1', 2: 'answer2', 3: 'answer3'}
```

Comment: To be honest the perl code i am not familiar with here is the function that asks for question 2 & 3. It is trying to match passwords. When I run this piece manually without the use of pexpect it never fails. So I suspected some kind of buffering with the send data being saved over to the next sendline() or smthing?

Comment: Thanks again! I found that one of my sendlines was not string stripped, it contained a /n inside of it. Ugh sorry for my mistake and thank you for your great response!